# C# Function that takes in value and prints out a 11x11 grid of values ranging -1 to 1

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

Currently learning C and in the textbook problem I am working on I have hit a slump. The question was Define a function that returns the value x^2 - y^2, and print out a 11 x 11 grid for values of x and y ranging from -1 to 1 using a function. I was able to finish the first row but I am having trouble with the other rows. The correct output to this problem is

```
   0.00    0.36    0.64    0.84    0.96    1.00    0.96    0.84    0.64    0.36    0.00 
  -0.36    0.00    0.28    0.48    0.60    0.64    0.60    0.48    0.28    0.00   -0.36 
  -0.64   -0.28    0.00    0.20    0.32    0.36    0.32    0.20   -0.00   -0.28   -0.64 
  -0.84   -0.48   -0.20    0.00    0.12    0.16    0.12   -0.00   -0.20   -0.48   -0.84 
  -0.96   -0.60   -0.32   -0.12    0.00    0.04   -0.00   -0.12   -0.32   -0.60   -0.96 
  -1.00   -0.64   -0.36   -0.16   -0.04    0.00   -0.04   -0.16   -0.36   -0.64   -1.00 
  -0.96   -0.60   -0.32   -0.12    0.00    0.04    0.00   -0.12   -0.32   -0.60   -0.96 
  -0.84   -0.48   -0.20    0.00    0.12    0.16    0.12    0.00   -0.20   -0.48   -0.84 
  -0.64   -0.28    0.00    0.20    0.32    0.36    0.32    0.20    0.00   -0.28   -0.64 
  -0.36    0.00    0.28    0.48    0.60    0.64    0.60    0.48    0.28    0.00   -0.36 
   0.00    0.36    0.64    0.84    0.96    1.00    0.96    0.84    0.64    0.36    0.00
```

So far in my code I have

```
double y=1;
int count =0;
double xSq;
double origX = x;
double origY = y;
double ySq;
xSq = x * x;
ySq = y * y;
double update;

for (int i =0; i < 11; i++){
     
    double sum = xSq - ySq;
    printf("%f\t", sum);
    count++;
    y = y - 0.2;
    ySq = y * y;
}
```

Comment: which language, `C#` or `C` ?

Comment: @tstanisl im sorry it was C, I didn't even know C# and C were different languages

Answer (score 0):

I think what they are wanting you to do is different. They want you to first makea function that returns the diff between squares.
Then, they want you to use that function from a 2 level loop (in main) which vary the values of x and y respectively.
The values x and y each go from -1 to +1.
Inside the 2 level loop, you'd call your function with the then current values of x, y and get the result. Then, you'd print x, y and the result.
You'll figure out how to add a line after one level of the loop so that you get your rows.